# Lock\Block on table with SPID -2

Tags: t-sql, locking, deadlock, spid

Hi I have a table with a lot of lock with the value of -2. I cannot kill the session id process using `kill` cmd. Does anyone know what SPID with `-2` means.

I run this query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(P.object_id) AS TableName,
       Resource_type,
       request_session_id
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks L
JOIN sys.partitions P ON L.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(P.object_id) = 'Table '
```

Sample Output

```
Table Name
ClaimRequest    

Resource_Type 
KEY / Page

request_session_id
-2
```

There are 23770 rows of data of this type

Answer (score 0):

Found out -2 is orphaned Transaction from Distributed Transaction. If you need to kill -2 SPID use this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4142/how-to-kill-a-blocking-negative-spid-in-sql-server/